# UTF8 TEXT coming back with weird symbols

Tags: php, mongodb, utf-8

Im storing text in a DB as UTF8.

When a post is sent via JS to my API, such symbols as ö come back as "Ã¶"

My website html is declared as

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

My API output is sent out with a header declaring utf-8, like so:

```
$status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 '.$status.' '.self::getStatusCodeMessage($status);
header($status_header);
header('Content-type: ' . $content_type.'; charset=utf-8');

if ($body !== '') {
    echo $body;
```

The only way I've managed to get round this is by using PHP on my output todo this:

```
private static function fixText($text) {

        $replaceChars = array(
            "â€œ" => "\"",
            'â€¢' => '·',
            "â€" => "\"",
            "â€™" => "'",
            'Ã¶' => 'ö',

            'â€' => "'",

            "Ã©" => "é",
            "Ã«" => "ë",
            "Â£" => "£"
        );
        foreach($replaceChars as $oldChar => $newChar) {
            $text = str_replace($oldChar, $newChar, $text);
        }

        $text = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $text);
        return $text;
    }
```

Obviously this is not ideal as I have to keep adding more and more symbols to the map.

---

UPDATE:

A developer had sneakily added this code:

```
$document->text = mb_convert_encoding($document->text, mb_detect_encoding($document->text), "cp1252");
```

As a way to overcome old latin characters coming through damaged.

Comment: What are the character set and collations of your db and tables ??

Comment: It's good that you showed your current workaround, but it would be better if you also gave more details about what you are doing exactly. A meta tag and an assertion that your API output is sent as utf-8 is not much to go on.

Comment: Sorry I'm using mongoDB, as far as I'm aware mongoDB is always utf-8. Updated code samples also.

Comment: See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/476) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) and [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/). I don't know the specific setting for working with MongoDB, but the concepts are always the same.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing those funny characters means that you have double-encoded UTF-8 stored. You don't show how you are adding data to the database. If you use `utf8_encode()` on already UTF-8 encoded strings, this will be your result.

MongoDB only accepts UTF-8 but you should not encoded it yourself again, if you're already gettings UTF-8 send through to you by the webserver.

Instead of:

```
header('Content-type: ' . $content_type.'; charset=utf-8');
```

Consider setting the default charset in `php.ini`:

```
default_charset=UTF-8
```